# SQLAlchemy 3 way join queries

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've seen other questions on this, but none of them quite fitted the bill.
I'm writing an app which runs various queries on a set of music data. The problem I have is this:
Say I have an instrument class like this:

```
class Instrument(Base, NamedMixin):

    diatonic = Column(Integer, default=0)
    chromatic = Column(Integer, default=0)

    pieces = relationship(
        "Piece",
        secondary=instrument_join_table,
        back_populates="instruments",
        lazy='dynamic')

    clefs = relationship(
        "Clef",
        secondary=clef_join_table,
        back_populates="instruments",
        lazy="dynamic"
    )

    keys = relationship(
        "Key",
        secondary=key_join_table,
        back_populates="instruments",
        lazy="dynamic"
    )
```

and a music element class called a clef like this:

```
class Clef(Base, NamedMixin):
    sign = Column(String)
    line = Column(Integer)

    pieces = relationship(
        "Piece",
        secondary=clef_join_table,
        back_populates="clefs",
        lazy='dynamic')

    instruments = relationship(
        "Instrument",
        secondary=clef_join_table,
        back_populates="clefs",
        lazy="dynamic"
        )
```

and a piece class like this:

```
class Piece(Base, NamedMixin):
    instruments = relationship(
        "Instrument",
        secondary=instrument_join_table,
        back_populates="pieces", lazy='dynamic')

    clefs = relationship(
        "Clef",
        secondary=clef_join_table,
        back_populates="pieces", lazy='dynamic')

    keys = relationship(
        "Key",
        secondary=key_join_table,
        back_populates="pieces", lazy='dynamic')
```

So I have a many to many to many relationship defined between both instruments, pieces and clefs, and instruments, keys and clefs. The instrument join table joins the piece id and the instrument id in one table, and the clef_join and key_join tables contain the piece id, instrument id, and clef id. Relevant joins:

```
instrument_join_table = Table(
'instrument_piece_join', Base.metadata, Column(
    'instrument_id', Integer, ForeignKey('instrument.id')), Column(
        'piece_id', Integer, ForeignKey('piece.id')))

clef_join_table = Table('clef_piece_join', Base.metadata,
                        Column('clef_id', Integer, ForeignKey('clef.id')),
                        Column('piece_id', Integer, ForeignKey('piece.id')),
                        Column('instrument_id', Integer, ForeignKey('instrument.id'))
                        )

key_join_table = Table('key_piece_join', Base.metadata,
                       Column('key_id', Integer, ForeignKey('key.id')),
                       Column('piece_id', Integer, ForeignKey('piece.id')),
                       Column('instrument_id', Integer, ForeignKey('instrument.id'))
                       )
```

And the base I'm using is the dynamic base. Named mixin has a name column and an ID column.

What I want to be able to query is a piece which contains an instrument which contains a clef.
Naturally I started by querying for the instrument, then filtering by the clef:

```
models = self.session.query(Instrument).filter_by(name=instrument)
ins_models = models.filter(Instrument.clefs.any(**kwarg)).all()
```

but then if you ask for the pieces from either of those two elements, you will get the pieces which the instrument has but may not be in the appropriate clef, or the pieces which contains the clef but don't necessarily have those instruments.

I have done this before using SQLAlchemy using pure SQL into a SQLite database, but I'm relatively new to SQLAlchemy so can't wrap my head around it. Is the best answer to have a new model, something like "InstrumentClefKeyMapping" or what have you or what? By this point I seem to be just throwing on more filters which isn't doing much.

This was the query I used when I did this in pure SQL:

```
SELECT clef_piece.piece_id FROM clef_piece_join clef_piece WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM clef_piece_join WHERE piece_id = clef_piece.piece_id AND instrument_id = ? AND clef_id = ?)
```

Then for each clef I added to the inner select and each instrument added AND EXISTS (another select query).

Comment: Could you include the associative (join) tables themselves as well in your question?

Comment: "...but then if you ask for the pieces from either of those two elements, you will get the pieces which the instrument has but may not be in the appropriate clef...", do you mean if you iterate over for example `instrument.pieces` or `clef.pieces`, where `instrument` and `clef` are results of your query?

Comment: As for your original SQL, why the `EXISTS` that semi-joins `clef_piece_join` to itself and then checks for instrument and clef? Would distinct not suffice? As that query shows you have all the required info in that table, use it with SQLAlchemy as well; query against it and join the `Piece` for fetching the orm instances.